# What is the difference between "SessionSubmit" and "LocalSubmit" in performance?

Tags: evaluation, parallelization, function-comparison

Does `SessionSubmit` forward the computation to the master thread and `LocalSubmit` to some other idle thread? By thread, I mean CPU core thread.

If this is true, can `LocalSubmit` be executed in parallel by different core while `SessionSubmit` is running on the master core?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but what i saw

```
SessionSubmit[Pause[10]]
```
blocks the whole session, it feels like all scheduled tasks created using SessionSubmit are executed sequentially. The only way to separate them is to use `LocalSubmit` at any core. But I guess the number is limited by the license.

Comment: The docs need to be better

Answer (score 3):

SessionSubmit will start a task in the same session as the foreground. However, LocalSubmit will start a new kernel, if available, and execute the code there. You can observe this behavior in the TaskManager.

Executing your code in several kernels is faster than if you only have one kernel. Of course, if you submit more tasks than you have kernels, the speed up  suffers.

Here is a timing example using local/Session submit and 4 tasks:

```
n = 10^5;
(LocalSubmit[Do[Sqrt[2], {n}]];
  LocalSubmit[Do[Sqrt[2], {n}]];
  LocalSubmit[Do[Sqrt[2], {n}]];
  LocalSubmit[Do[Sqrt[2], {n}]];) // AbsoluteTiming

(SessionSubmit[Do[Sqrt[2], {n}]];
  SessionSubmit[Do[Sqrt[2], {n}]];
  SessionSubmit[Do[Sqrt[2], {n}]];
  SessionSubmit[Do[Sqrt[2], {n}]];) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {7.118, Null} *)
(* {0.0005934, Null} *)
```

However, if we submit 8 tasks on a machine with 4 kernels, the time will  approx. double:

```
(SessionSubmit[Do[Sqrt[2], {n}]];
  SessionSubmit[Do[Sqrt[2], {n}]];
  SessionSubmit[Do[Sqrt[2], {n}]];
  SessionSubmit[Do[Sqrt[2], {n}]];
  SessionSubmit[Do[Sqrt[2], {n}]];
  SessionSubmit[Do[Sqrt[2], {n}]];
  SessionSubmit[Do[Sqrt[2], {n}]];
  SessionSubmit[Do[Sqrt[2], {n}]];) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.0011649, Null} *)
```

Comment: That's helpful.  So that means I would need to `DistributeDefinitions` if I want LocalSubmit to work?

Comment: Yes, different kernels do not know each others data.